# how to save documents in custom location on sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

is there anyway to configure sharepoint so that the documents will save in the file system instead of saving to the database

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to setup the FILESTREAM provider

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee663474.aspx